When running my Django test suite in VS Code, I get `AF_UNIX path too long`
I'm having a problem with the VS Code test runner.  It has worked as expected, but not when I load my nix environment in VS Code.
I'd like to be able to:

Have direnv load the nix environment in the VS Code environment, to mirror my shell setup
Have the VS Code test runner discover and run Django tests

To load the nix env, I'm using this direnv plugin, which:

adds direnv support to Visual Studio Code by loading environment variables for the workspace root.

But VS Code cannot discover tests.  In the Python Test Log in the Output tab, I see:
pvsc_utils.VSCodeUnittestError: DJANGO ERROR: An error occurred while discovering and building the test suite. Error: Error attempting to connect to extension named pipe /var/folders/l3/tn48czyn38nfr8dqkfbyf8_40000gn/T/nix-shell.MXciF0/python-test-discovery-a054ebbeef511140679d.sock[vscode-unittest]: AF_UNIX path too long

The path is exceeding long because the socket is now created in the nix env.  Is there a way to modify the location that the socket will be created?
I tried to set TMPDIR in my .envrc, but that did not change anything.  It looks like nix unsets TMPDIR.
